# Cast Array<String?> to Array<String> in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, casting

I have an array of nulls that I initialize with Strings. Then I have to pass it to a function that requires `Array<String>` instead of `Array<String?>`. So how can I go around this issue?

```
val list_names = arrayOfNulls<String>(plant_list.size)
for(item in plant_list){ list_names.plus(item.name) }

val myListAdapter = MyListAdapter(activity!!,list_names,list_types,list_images) // list_names must be Array<String>
```

I also want to mention that changing it in the Adapter would only complicate things, so I would like to do it all from here.

Comment: "Array instead of Array" what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that no `null`-values will be in your nullable array, you can simply (unsafe) cast it and it will work, e.g.:

```
val myListAdapter = MyListAdapter(activity!!,list_names as Array<String>,list_types,list_images)
```

If you have `null` values in there it depends a bit. One approach is then to first filter out the `null`-values and pass the resulting array, e.g.:

```
list_names.filterNotNull().toTypedArray()
// or in case you have different types in there and want only want a single matching one:
list_names.filterIsInstance<String>().toTypedArray()
```

But if you can: try to omit holding that array of nullable type in the first place. Can't you just filter out null values and collect the non-nullable only? That would probably the easiest and nicest way to collect the names as `Array<String>`, e.g.:

```
val list_names = plant_list.mapNotNull { it.name }.toTypedArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your direct question you can get a new Array without nulls using this:

```
val nonNullListNames = list_names.filterNotNull().toTypedArray()
```

But there are other issues with your code. There's no reason to create the array of nulls and add items to it. Every time you call `list_names.plus(item.name)` in your loop, you are creating a new Array that still has the original set of null values plus your new item(s).

Instead you can directly create a list of non-null items from the collection you're getting items from, and convert it to an Array:

```
val nonNullNamesArray = plant_list.map { it.name }.toTypedArray()
```

If your plant names are nullable, use this:

```
val nonNullNamesArray = plant_list.mapNotNull { it.name }.toTypedArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a arrayOfNulls and convert a Nullable to a NonNull object.
What I recommend to you is:

```
val list_names = mutableListOf<String>()
plant_list.foreach {
    list_names.add(it.name)
}
val myListAdapter = MyListAdapter(activity, list_names, list_types, list_images)
```